# In Chrome DevTools, When done Timeline recording, What is millisecond of sources Panel means?

Tags: google-chrome, devtools, timeline

As you visit https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance and find "Layout Forced" keyword, and you can see the picture of the left panel showing 23.9 ms.

I can't know what is the mean, it is mean executing this line using cpu time? but I found some record in code line only has "}", and this have a value say 1.2 ms, and some value only a definition also have a value 0.4 ms, but next definition have no value. So I don't know what this exact mean.

[This is picture that I can't understand](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxsMQ.png)

Answer (score 1):

In general, the times in the margin are how long was spent running that line of code. But for function declarations, it's the overhead of calling that function. No idea what it means for closing braces '}' of for loops.

Here's an example: https://imgur.com/a/dEP9lAK

- Calling the function and the for loop have a little overhead (line 10 & 12).
- Adding 2 numbers is super fast (line 14).
- Multiplying and calling Math.random() takes a bit more time (line 13 & 16)
- Math.cos, `**` and `/` take even more time (line 15)

1 thing to keep in mind, if you use source mapping, it might be off a bit. It took me a while to figure out when developing a typescript app why the times didn't make sense; e.g. why something simple like `a = 2` was taking 1s while a complicated line below it was taking 1ms. When I turned off source mapping, it became apparent the 1s actually represented the complicated line.

Comment: Thanks for the "source mapping" reminder - I keep forgetting about this...